# Can I pour concrete if it's raining out?

Tags: concrete

I have 6 bags of concrete that I need to mix and pour for 2 deck piers.
It's raining lightly outside.

Should I reschedule or just do it and cover with plastic when we're done?

Answer (score 4):

If you're manually mixing under cover (garage, gazebo, kitchen fly) and only dumping when ready, then no problem.

Definitely cover in case of heavier rain.  Its never a bad idea to slow cure concrete, anyway.  Plastic can make flat work look bad (plastic wrinkles), but for deck piers, no problem.

Now get to work and quit stalling by playing on the computer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is lightly raining you have nothing to worry about especially for piers.  Extra water just raises the cure time.  I would try to wipe off any standing water after you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Heavy rain: Not advisable, but has been done (you end up working the finished side up more, as the rain and runoff can ding the finish.

Light rain: Cover the work area if possible. If it is a foundation or other project with a form: No problem.

In general: allow lots of cure time, and wait until the concrete is cold to the touch (it is usually very slightly warm while it is curing)